# Getting total installations of my application with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the number of users who have installed my application. I am sending a fql query built based on the information:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#Metrics

Due to this instruction i need to call for metric 'application_installed_users' with period 'lifetime' and end_time not specified.

I tried in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/ to call:

`SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=<my_app_id> AND metric='application_installed_users' AND period=period('lifetime')`

This query gives the following error:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "You must specify a bounded date range using unix time stamps as constant values.", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}`

so I also tried:

`SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=<my_app_id> AND metric='application_installed_users' AND end_time=0 AND period=period('lifetime')`

whick results in empty data.

What is the proper query for calling for 'application_installed_users' ??

Cheers,
Maciek

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Facebook's [documentation for the insights table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights), you'll see some fields marked with a half-filled star. These are their index fields, and you must supply values for all of these fields in your WHERE clause.

In your case, you're receiving an empty data package because you're asking for end_time=0, which is limiting the data to the start of epoch time. Try supplying recent end_time and that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this `... AND end_time = end_time_date('2013-04-04') ...` and it worked.